# ixgbe eth0: initiating reset due to tx timeout and ixgbe eth0: Reset adapter

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, nic, drivers

Server interfaces are flapping sometimes. It happens randomly. We are getting below logs in dmesg and similar logs are being captured in syslog as well.

OS:

```
OS-Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Details:

```
driver: ixgbe
version: 4.4.0-k
firmware-version: 0x80001112
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:41:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Logs:

```
ixgbe 0000:41:00.0 eth0: initiating reset due to tx timeout
ixgbe 0000:41:00.0 eth0: Reset adapter
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: initiating reset due to tx timeout
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: Reset adapter
ixgbe 0000:41:00.0 eth0: speed changed to 0 for port eth0
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: speed changed to 0 for port eth1
bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth0, disabling it
bond0: now running without any active interface!
bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth1, disabling it
ixgbe 0000:41:00.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth0, 10000 Mbps full duplex
bond0: first active interface up!
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth1, 10000 Mbps full duplex
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: initiating reset due to tx timeout
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: Reset adapter
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: speed changed to 0 for port eth1
bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth1, disabling it
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth1, 10000 Mbps full duplex
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: initiating reset due to tx timeout
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: Reset adapter
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: speed changed to 0 for port eth1
bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth1, disabling it
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth1, 10000 Mbps full duplex
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: initiating reset due to tx timeout
ixgbe 0000:41:00.1 eth1: Reset adapter
sched: RT throttling activated
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by low-level problems while the NIC transmits the ethernet frames.

General advices:

- check the statistics from NIC (`ethtool -S eth0 | grep tx`)
- check the logs from remote side device
- replace SFP-modules/DAC-cables
- update the NIC driver - build and install ixgbe module from the [Intel site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14687/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-).

Comment: Thanks, I have upgraded the driver to the latest version. Since the issue happens randomly, I am not able to come to a conclusion if it is resolved. Sometimes I get below logs when the server is unreachable. What could be the issue? Please help.

[ 7935.620040] sched: RT throttling activated
[ 7948.022799] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 7948.022807] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 49264 at /build/linux-dqnRSc/linux-4.9.228/net/sched/sch_generic.c:316 dev_watchdog+0x233/0x240
[ 7948.022807] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (ixgbe): transmit queue 54 timed out

Comment: Please show the updated version of `ethtool -i eth0` and also show the output of command `ethtool -k eth0`. Try to disable GRO and TSO offloads if they are enabled. Also show the output of `lspci -vvv -s 41:00.1`.

Comment: driver: ixgbe
version: 5.11.3
firmware-version: 0x80001112, 1.2684.0
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:41:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

Comment: tcp-segmentation-offload: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off [fixed]
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off

Comment: to disable offloads: `ethtool -k eth0 gso off tso off gro off`. If the issue will be repeat, then try to build and install vanilla kernel (prefer LTS version).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ill try that. Can you also please clarify what should we check at remote device/Switch end?